# finite-difference operator and scalar product in $L_{2}(a,b)$

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let:

$$\Delta_{h}f(x)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Prove that for any finite function $f\in L_{2}(a,b)$ and any function $g\in L_{2}(a,b)$, following formula holds:

$$\left(\Delta_{h}f,g\right)_{L_{2}(a,b)}=-\left(f,\Delta_{-h}g\right)_{L_{2}(a,b)}$$

Here is my take on it, using the fact that $f(x)$ is finite on $(a,b)$, which means equal $0$ for $x\notin(a,b)$:

\begin{align}
(\Delta_{h}f,g)_{L_{2}(a,b)} & = \int_{a}^{b}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\,\overline{g(x)}\,dx \\
& =\int_{a}^{b}\frac{f(x+h)\,\overline{g(x)}}{h}\,dx-\int_{a}^{b}\frac{f(x)\,\overline{g(x)}}{h}\,dx \\
& =\int_{a+h}^{b+h}\frac{f(x)\,\overline{g(x-h)}}{h}\,dx-\int_{a}^{b}\frac{f(x)\,\overline{g(x)}}{h}\,dx \\
& =\int_{a+h}^{b}\frac{f(x)\,\overline{g(x-h)}}{h}\,dx-\int_{a}^{b}\frac{f(x)\,\overline{g(x)}}{h}\,dx \\
& =\int_{a}^{b}\frac{f(x)\,\overline{g(x-h)}}{h}\,dx-\int_{a}^{b}\frac{f(x)\,\overline{g(x)}}{h}\,dx-\int_{a}^{a+h}\frac{f(x)\,\overline{g(x-h)}}{h}\,dx \\
& =\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,\left(-\frac{\overline{g(x-h)}-\overline{g(x)}}{-h}\right)\,dx-\int_{a}^{a+h}\frac{f(x)\,\overline{g(x-h)}}{h}\,dx \\
& =-\left(f,\Delta_{-h}g\right)_{L_{2}(a,b)}-\int_{a}^{a+h}\frac{f(x)\,\overline{g(x-h)}}{h}\,dx \\
\end{align}

So there is a superfluous term $-\int_{a}^{a+h}\frac{f(x)\,\overline{g(x-h)}}{h}\,dx$, but it doesn't seem possible to eliminate it.  Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 0):

> Here is my take on it, using the fact that $f(x)$ is finite on $(a,b)$, which means equal $0$ for $x\neq(a,b)$

You can use the same argument for $g(x)$. Rewrite this *superfluous* term as
\begin{equation}
-\int_{a-h}^a\frac{f(x+h)\overline{g(x)}}{h}dx
\end{equation}
$\overline{g(x)}$ is $0$ in the range of integration. So this whole term is $0$.

Comment: But the problem statement is not saying that $g(x)$ is finite, like it says for $f(x)$, so we cannot assume that $g(x)=0$ for $x\notin(a,b)$.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. However, I have a question for you, why the fact that $f(x)$ is finite on $(a,b)$ makes it $0$ outside this range? That is the reason I cited you above, because I myself can't understand the reason for that.

Comment: In my understanding, finite on $(a,b)$ means that $f(x)\neq \infty$ for $x\in (a,b)$. And we don't apply this limitation on $g(x)$

Comment: The word "finite" is used here in the sense of term "finite support" from functional analysis, which means that the function $f(x)=0$ everywhere except for some subset of $(a,b)$ interval.